# Set the default value of argument as parameter in newcommand

Tags: macros, indexing

I want to define a command that will emphasis the keywords and add it to the index at the same time. This can be archived by

```
\newcommand{\iemph}[1]{\emph{#1}\index{#1}}
```

But the problem is that, I want also to use the variant of index: `\index{bundle!Vector bundle}` which means the `vector bundle` should be indexed under the index `bundle`, I try to accomplish it as

```
\newcommand{\iemph}[2][]{\emph{#2}\index{#1!#2}}
```

That means, I set the first value default be empty, but this not give me the desired results (it is not indexed at all) when I suppress the first argument:

```
 \iemph{vector bundle}
```

Although it works perfectly in the full form

```
 \iemph{vector}{Vector bundle}
```

or

```
 \iemph[vector]{vector bundle}
```

So is there any solution to this problem without define two command? If we can define something like:

```
\newcommand{\iemph}[2][]{\emph{#2}\if{#1 is not empty}{\index{#1!#2}}else{\index{#2}}}
```

**UPDATE**

Maybe the simple solution to the original problem--although the answer privided below is also useful in someother similar situation--is define the command as

```
\newcommand{\iemph}[2][]{\emph{#2}\index{#1#2}}
```

and use it as

```
\iemph{vector bundle}
\iemph[vector!]{vector bundle}
```

It should be noted that in this case

```
\iemph{vector!}{vector bundle}
```

behaves weird.

Comment: I assume you mean `parameter`, not `paramentor`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `\NewDocumentCommand` from the `xparse` package, it's quite easy to ask whether the optional argument is given or not:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\iemph}{om}{%
  \emph{#2}%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \index{#1!#2}%
  }{%
    \index{#2}%
  }%
}
```

Here `o` means optional argument and with `\IfValueTF{#1}{true}{false}` it's possible to do the relevant branching.

Another possibility: Use `\ifblank{}{}{}` from the `etoolbox` package, as shown in `\iemphother`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}    
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{xparse}


\newcommand{\iemphother}[2][]{%
  \emph{#2}%
  \ifblank{#1}{%
    \index{#2}%
  }{%
  \index{#1!#2}%
  }%
}



\NewDocumentCommand{\iemph}{om}{%
  \emph{#2}%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \index{#1!#2}%
  }{%
    \index{#2}%
  }%
}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
\iemph[vector]{vector bundle}

\iemph{vector bundle}



\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: One could do `\newcommand{\iemph}[2][\@gobble]{\emph{#2}\index{#1!#2}}`, but it's better to avoid trickery when more robust methods are available.

Comment: @egreg: I am not really into `\@gobble` so far (you won't be surprised, I assume ;-)), so I leave trickery to you ;-)

Comment: @egreg could you explain the trick? I have just learnt that `\@gobble` throw away its argument, but how this could work here?

Comment: @user19832 `\index` performs one level expansion, so it expands `\@gobble` if it's the first token in the argument; this expansion gobbles the `!`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, but `\iemph{a}` or `\iemph{a}{a}` will output right, but will not index properly, As it is indexed under the entry: `m gobble`, don't know how to fix. BTW, `\iemph[a]{a}`will work.

Comment: @user19832 I said: “it's better to avoid trickery when more robust methods are available”. Since a more robust method is available, why trying trickery?